# I am trying to implement OOP concepts with java

Tags: java, oop

When i try to compile an aggregation program , i receive an error saying "class,interface,enum expected". Here is my code. please help me solve this issue.

```
class employee
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private float salary;

    public employee(String na, String add,float sal)
    {
        name = na;
        address = add;
        salary = sal;
    }   

    public void showEmpDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
        System.out.println("Address " + address);
        System.out.println("Salary " + salary );
        System.out.println();
    }

}

import java.util.vector;

class company
{
    private String comname;
    private vector vt;

    public company(String na)
    {
        comname = na;
        vt = new vector();
    }   

    public void addEmployee(employee e)
    {
        vt.addElement(e);
    }

    public void showComDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Company Name " + comname);

        int x = vt.size();
        int y = 0;
        while(y<x)
        {
            object e = vt.elementAt(y);
            e.showEmpDetails();
            y++;
        }
    }
}

public class demo
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        employee e1 = new employee("Ashan","Kandy",2000.0f);
        employee e2 = new employee("Steve","California",2500.0f);
        employee e3 = new employee("Elon","South Africa",2500.0f);

        company c1 = new company("Apple");

        c1.addEmployee(e1);
        c1.addEmployee(e2);
        c1.addEmployee(e3);

        c1.showComDetails();
    }
}
```

Note:- i receive only one error. and also can anybody tell me why can't i have more than one public class in java.

Comment: Can I assume that each class is in its own file

Comment: `vector` should be `Vector` and unless you some incredibly important reason for using it, you might want to use `ArrayList` instead

Comment: `object` should be `Object`...you might want to have a look at [Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) which will help you solve the next problem

Comment: The convention for naming classes in Java is to use Pascal case. like this: `public class Employee`.

Comment: As @MadProgrammer alluded to in his first comment, standard practice is to use exactly one file per class, and use the same name for both the class and file. Class names should begin with a capital letter. Employee vs employee. Lowercase is for variables, like the ones that hold instances of objects.

Comment: Try capitalizing `object`, since `object` isn't a built-in type. That's probably the cause of your error.

Comment: Also, don't declare variables in a loop (`object e = `...). You would declare outside `Object e;` and then only do the assignment part inside the loop.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple And the benefit would be? (Serious, I'm curious)

Comment: Declaring isn't free.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple I am on the opposite side: declare in scope that is going to use it.  I wonder how much extra overhead it adds for extra declarations but the benefits of declaring the variable within the required scope will doubtless cover the overhead

Comment: @LinuxDisciple Just for my curiosity, I wrote a little class with 2 methods: both are a simple loop, with only difference being an extra var declared inside and outside the loop.  It turned out the byte code generated is almost identical (and no extra instructions within the loop).  So, in this aspect, declaring is actually **free**.

Comment: Hypothesis plus test wins. Looks like I'll be instantiating differently in a few cases from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code has more than one error actually. The reason for your specific error is that `import` should be at beginning of the file, not in the middle.

And my understanding of why only one public class is allowed for each file is:

1. It makes things clearer.

   By reading the class name and document to this class, you could quickly know what the whole file is used for. If we allow multiple public classes in one file, like C++, then we have to jump inside of the file to understand it.

   Notice Java is a strong object-oriented language, i.e. everything in Java is Object. So when importing, you are importing a file. It would be more complicated if one file contains multiple public classes.
2. It simplify testing.

   Each public class could have a `main` function. And you could run any `main` function of a file `Demo.java` simply by `java Demo`. This is really nice, so that you could write test code, or example of usage in `main` function to show other contributor how this class should be used.

There have to be other more in-depth reason for single public class in Java. But these are my perspective.